# Get promise from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In view ng-repeat start renderning. When a assign an array to the scope variable,

```
html
<div ng-repeat="l in languages">{{l.name}}</div>

js
$rootScope.languages = data.languages
// I want a promise of ng-repeat completed here. 
setTimeout (->
  $rootScope.language = data.languages[0];
),200
```

Now I'm using setTimeout. But its not proper way

Comment: it is not a clear question. what you exactly want? Please explain it with details even support it with a plunk...

Answer (score 0):

There may not be such a promise out-of-box. But it's somehow possible to achieve the goal with `ng-repeat`'s `$last`. Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<div ng-repeat="l in languages" ng-init="testLast($last)">{{l.name}}</div>
```

And,

```
$rootScope.testLast = function($last) {
    if($last) {
        // whatever you intended for the promise
    }
}
```

It's also possible to create a directive for this if better isolation is wanted.